How to get the Ousia block to appear in the dry Orthant of Memory?
I visited the Orthant of Memory, that from Wiki context seems to be under the Morte region's Statue of the Seven, and I think I solved it except for the Arkhe puzzle, in which I only managed one of two portions due to finding an Ousia block on the second floor, the one seen in this video timestamp at the upper left of center.

Then when I went back after realizing that the Traveller has Pneumo abilities that could solve it.
But after defeating the Rifthounds again, the Ousia block didn't reappear and I somehow got the option to Check / examine the central mechanism when I didn't get the option the first time I completed the main puzzle, and the Ousia block I found last time isn't here, I have to flood the place to solve the Arkhe puzzle.
What triggers the Ousia block on the second floor?
